# Flutter : Class 'Future<List<String>>' has no instance getter 'length'

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, provider

I have a List of String saved on SharedPreference in Flutter app, I want to call it inside Provider and using it in a widget.
Provider :

```
get myTeam => getMyTeam();
  Future<List<String>> getMyTeam() async {
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    return prefs.getStringList('team');
  }
```

I used it in future builder :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GeneralProvider>(
        builder: (context, generalProvider, child) {
      var items = generalProvider.myTeam;
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: items,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('${items[index].club}'),
                    );
                  });
            } else {
              return Text('bad');
            }
          });
    });
  }
```

I get error : `Class 'Future<List<String>>' has no instance getter 'length'`

I tied with many solutions in questions here like :
[Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'length'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643229/class-futuredynamic-has-no-instance-getter-length)

but it wasn't solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `itemCount: items.length` into `itemCount: snapshot.length`,

And Future builder to `FutureBuilder<List<String>(...etc)`.

Will look like this in the end:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GeneralProvider>(
        builder: (context, generalProvider, child) {
      var items = generalProvider.myTeam;
      return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
          future: items,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                     // title: Text('${items[index].club}'),//This will likely throw an error also, because items is a List<String>, there is no method called "club" for Lists. 
                    //Replace it with this to validate:
                    title: Text(snapshot[index]),//This 
   
                    );
                  });
            } else {
              return Text('bad');
            }
          });
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you ,the error of length is solved but no data load

Comment: Could be a render flex error by using listview and listTiles, or that your data object has a problem.